# Reading a csv file in Golang function executed in browser

Tags: typescript, go, webassembly

I have written a script in Golang to sort user stories stored in a csv and create sprints with a fixed team velocity.
The following is the part related to reading the csv file.

```golang
// userstory.go
f, err := os.Open("userstories.csv")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
} the file at the end of the program
defer f.Close()
csvReader := csv.NewReader(f)
data, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
```

Now, since I **aim to make it work in the browser (with no backend)** and the golang code is compiled to wasm, I can't use os files anymore.

So I'm trying [to get the ArrayBuffer from the File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) and pass it as an `Uint8Array` argument (from JavaScript) to the function `GetSprints`:

```
// js code
const runScript = async () => {
  let files = data.fileList;    

  files[0].arrayBuffer().then((x) => {
    var b = new Uint8Array(x);
    console.log(b)
    console.log(GetSprints(b));
  })
}
```

`GetSprints` has been exposed to JavaScript with the following `js.Global().Set`:

```
// userstory.go
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go WebAssembly: loaded UserStory.go")
    js.Global().Set("GetSprints", getSprintsWrapper())
    <-make(chan bool)
}
```

and the `Uint8Array` passed as first argument, is copied to a `[]byte` buffer:

```
// userstory.go
func getSprintsWrapper() js.Func {
    getSprintsFunc := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        var dst []byte
        js.CopyBytesToGo(dst, args[0])

        return GetSprints(dst)
    })
    return getSprintsFunc
}
```

Given that [csv.NewReader](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#NewReader) accepts a [io.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) as argument, i tried to replace the file descriptor with [bytes.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#NewReader)

```golang
// userstory.go
func GetSprints(inputFile []byte) []Sprint {
  f := bytes.NewReader(inputFile)
  csvReader := csv.NewReader(f)
  data, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Println("No errors reading csv. Data: ", data)
  // ...
}
```

but it results in an empty array.
[image]

Someone else interested in parsing files with golang code compiled to wasm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It worked replacing the **arrayBuffer()** method with [text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text).

The method **text()** *"returns"* (allow me the term but it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)) a UTF-8 string representing the content of the file.

```js
// js code
const runScript = async () => {
  
  let files = data.fileList;    
  files[0].text().then((x) => {
    console.log(GetSprints(x));
  })
}
```

Then on the golang side, before passing the string, I converted it to `[]byte`

```golang
// userstory.go
func getSprintsWrapper() js.Func {
    getSprintsFunc := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        fmt.Println([]byte(args[0].String()))
        return GetSprints([]byte(args[0].String()))
    })
    return getSprintsFunc
}
```

and the `GetSprints` is finally able to process the csv.

```golang
// userstory.go
func GetSprints(inputFile []byte) []Sprint {
    f := bytes.NewReader(inputFile)
    csvReader := csv.NewReader(f)

    fmt.Println(csvReader.Read())
    data, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("No errors reading csv. Data: ", data)
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** Added a JSON.parse call on the js

```
// js
files[0].text().then((x) => {
 var sprints = JSON.parse(GetSprints(x));
   console.log(sprints);
})
```

and json.Marshal on golang side

```
// userstory.go
func getSprintsWrapper() js.Func {
    getSprintsFunc := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        b, err := json.Marshal(GetSprints([]byte(args[0].String())))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        return string(b)
    })
    return getSprintsFunc
}
```

so now the results can be handled as javascript objects.
[image]

If anyone has any suggestions to improve it, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: What kind of suggestions are you expecting once it's working?

Comment: You're right and I edited specifying "any suggestions to improve it". Thanks.